# Se usar libs "provided" no servidor de aplicações (wildfly), eu ganho performance?

Tags: java-ee, jboss, wildfly

imaginem o seguinte cenário. Eu tenho um servidor de aplicação WildFly 8.0.0 rodando com configurações *default* de "fábrica". Nesse servidor eu rodo 4 aplicações web simples. Essas aplicações usam algumas libs iguais como:

- Spring Framework;
- Primefaces;
- Spring Security;
- ...

Só que cada aplicação empacota as libs que ela própria usa. Então ela empacota os jars do spring, do primefaces, alguns commons e assim vai. Na verdade todas as aplicações fazem esse empacotamento em `WEB-INF/lib`. Inclusive elas empacotam a mesma versão do Spring, do Primefaces...

Agora vem algumas dúvidas:

1. Se eu retirar as libs comuns entre as aplicações e colocar no WildFly `/standalone/lib` e setar essas libs como `provided` eu ganharia performance nessas apps?
2. Caso haja versões diferentes empacotadas nas aplicações, isso pode dar problema? Por exemplo: em uma aplicação eu coloco o Spring 3.0 e na outra empacoto o Spring 4.0. Isso pode gerar conflito em alguma das aplicações ou o WildFly isola essas libs para uma não interferir na outra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em tese você pode ter vários benefícios ao usar compartilhar as mesmas bibliotecas entre as diversas aplicações:

1. **Menor uso de memória**, já que haverá apenas uma instância de cada classe, no Classloader das bibliotecas compartilhadas, ao invés de uma para cada cada aplicação, no Classloader particular criada para cada uma delas.
2. **Menor tempo de inicialização**, pois o servidor de aplicação não precisará carregar todas as classes novamente no *deploy*.
3. **Menor uso de banda e *deploy* mais rápido**, pois o pacote fica bem menor. Aplicações Java que tenho visto possuem pacotes na faixa de 50 a 100MB, só que o código da aplicação em si tem em geral 10% desse tamanho, sendo o resto apenas composto por bibliotecas de terceiros.
4. **Melhor desempenho**, se considerarmos a maior possibilidade de utilização de cache que a JVM e o sistema operacional podem fazer já que as classes executadas são as mesmas.

Porém, existem também algumas desvantagens:

1. Todas as aplicações precisam estar atualizadas para usar as mesmas versões de todas as APIs, o que é frequentemente inviável num ambiente corporativo.
2. A atualização de uma API precisa ser sincronizada com a atualização de todas as aplicações, o que dificulta muito a administração dos servidores.
3. A montagem do pacote WAR ou EAR das aplicações deve ser cuidadoso, pois se uma aplicação contiver as mesmas dependências da lib compartilhada, poderão ocorrer os "temidos" conflitos de Classloader, que geram erros bizarros e difíceis de identificar.

Falando mais especificamente sobre os problemas de classes diferentes em Classloaders diferentes, isso não dignifica que **sempre** ocorrerão problemas. Mas se houverem duas versões da mesma biblioteca, pode ocorrer do Wildfly carregar as classes que você não gostaria que ele carregasse.

Isso ocorria muito comigo comigo no Tomcat. A regra geral é: *o container sempre vai carregar a versão **incorreta** da classe!*

Outra abordagem que daria um pouco mais de flexibilidade é o uso de [módulos](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly). Você poderia empacotar cada framework em um módulo customizado e fazer suas aplicações dependerem desses módulos. Esta é uma alternativa interessante porque permite cada aplicação usar apenas as libs necessárias e inclusive versões diferentes do mesmo framework.

A criação de módulos é uma técnica comum para adicionar novos drivers de bancos de dados, como descrito [neste link](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/).

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava. Então, se teoricamente, eu estabelecer uma arquitetura bem definida de componentes em versões entre as aplicações além de definir um desenvolvimento "estrito", vai tender a facilitar depois a atualizações de componentes. Porém esse cenário nunca é perfeito. Obrigado!